# JasperReports line spacing

Tags: jasper-reports

I am developing a report with one Detail Band and one field that uses conditional styles. I am using Courier. The spacing between the lines is too large.

How can I minimize the space between the lines so the lines are nearly touching?

Below is the report XML.

```xml
<style name="DataHeaderTypeStyle">
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{lineSectionType}==1]]></conditionExpression>
        <style fontName="Courier New" fontSize="11"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
    <conditionalStyle>
        <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$F{lineSectionType}==2]]></conditionExpression>
        <style fontName="Courier New" fontSize="7"/>
    </conditionalStyle>
</style>
<queryString>
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>
<field name="lineSectionData" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[lineSectionData]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="lineSectionType" class="java.lang.Integer">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[lineSectionType]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<background>
    <band splitType="Stretch"/>
</background>
<detail>
    <band height="14" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
            <reportElement style="DataHeaderTypeStyle" positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="0" y="1" width="555" height="13">
                <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{lineSectionType}==1 || $F{lineSectionType}==2]]></printWhenExpression>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement>
                <font fontName="Courier New" pdfFontName="Courier"/>
                <paragraph lineSpacing="Fixed"/>
            </textElement>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{lineSectionData}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

Answer (score 12):

Set Jaspersoft Studio properties for "Text field" or "Static text" as follows:

- **Line spacing** for `Proportional`
- **Line Spacing Size** to `0.4` (or similar)

The XML source should resemble:

```
<textElement>
    <font fontName="Courier"/>
    <paragraph lineSpacing="Proportional" lineSpacingSize="0.4"/>
</textElement>
```